# ¿Como se puede mostrar el porcentaje de carga con dialog y AsyncAsk?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, progressdialog

estoy leyendo un json con una funcion asyncAsk, quiero mostrar en un dialog la descarga de los datos, pero el dialog se me cierra enseguida, y cuando no lo pongo a que se oculte no muestra la actualizacion de carga, sino cuando termina se muestra solo el 100%, este es el codigo de la función que estoy usando.

```
private class Productos2LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {
JSONArray resultado=null;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    txt_tot_pro.setText("Espere... Conectando");
    dialogbtn.setCancelable(false);
    dialogbtn.setTitle("Please wait");
    dialogbtn.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialogbtn.show();
}
@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try{
        mDbHelper.BorrarProductos();
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: urlproductos "+url_productos);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url_productos,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try
                        {
                            txt_tot_pro.setText("Espere... procesando");
                            resultado=response;
                            dialogbtn.setIndeterminate(false);
                            dialogbtn.setMax(resultado.length());
                            Log.i(TAG, "doBackground: resultado " + resultado.toString());
                            // hideProgress();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "parseJsonProductos ",e );
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                try{
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "ErrorProductos: " + error.getMessage());
                    Log.i(TAG, "onErrorResponseProductos: "+error.getMessage());
                    SyncReceive(posSyncRe);
                    Log.i("abd", "ErrorProductos: " + error
                            + ">>" + error.getCause()
                            + ">>" + error.getMessage());
                    txt_tot_pro.setText("Ocurrio un error al conectarse al servidor");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: ",e );
                }

            }

        });
        jsonArrayReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                //DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                15000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(jsonArrayReq);
    }catch (Exception error){
        Log.i(TAG, "parseJsonProductos error: " + error.toString());
    }
    return resultado;
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray cursor) {
    super.onPostExecute(cursor);
    try{
        JSONObject obj=null;
        Log.i(TAG, "total Productos: "+resultado.length());

        for (int a=0; a<resultado.length();a++) {
            // comdetalle cbdet=null;
            obj = resultado.getJSONObject(a);
            dialogbtn.setProgress(a);
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: r -- a:"+ a +" - "+obj.getString("IMA_ARTICULO"));
            //public rutas(String codigo, String descripcion, String rdcodigo, String cliente, String dia, String orden) {
            //showProgress("Producto "+response.length(),a);
            txt_tot_pro.setText("Sincronizando ("+String.valueOf(a) +")");
            save_producto=new producto(
                    obj.getString("IMA_ARTICULO"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_DESCRIPCION"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_LINEA"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_IMPUESTO"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_COSTO_PROMEDIO"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO1"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO2"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO3"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO4"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO5"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO6"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO7"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO8"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO9"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_PRECIO10"),
                    obj.getString("IMA_SUBLINEA"),
                    obj.getString("EXISTENCIA"),
                    obj.getString("PACK"),"1","cb");
            mDbHelper.nuevoProducto(save_producto);
        }
        txt_tot_pro.setText("Listo,("+resultado.length()+") sincronizacion completa");
        SyncReceive(posSyncRe);
    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute: ",e );
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute: ", e);
    }
    dialogbtn.dismiss();
}}
```

Lo que me parece raro es que la funcion ask el doBackground es como se ejecutará luego del onPostExecute, he intentado usando variables generales dentro de la clase pero no logro, también retornando las variables entre las funciones de la clase ask tampoco lo logró.

Espero sus comentarios.

Comment: No veo mucha lógica  a poner un % a un request ya que no puedes hacer una estimación real de lo que tardara, tiene más lógica al cargar datos de un fichero externo que puedes calcular la dimensión antes de empezar.

Comment: Intento leer un json desde el servidor, el proceso de doBackground se ejecuta despues del onPostExecute.  Como podría entonces mostrar la carga o el tiempo de espera, porque a veces el servidor demora en responder. En el mejor de los casos debo mostrar la carga.

Comment: Lo que se suele utilizar en estos casos es un spinner sin tanto % par que el usuario se de cuenta que la aplicación no se ha quedado colgada y esta realizando el request

Comment: te recomendaría que utilices un ProgressDialog , así pese a la demora el usuario podrá ver el progress cargando..

Comment: Estimado Gerard_jcr eso estoy usando en el ejemplo, un progressDialog, pero no se muestra el avance, sino que directamente pasa al postExecute, no se que esta pasado de que no muestra el proceso de los datos.